# Сравнение IP-адреса с диапазоном IP-адресов

Tags: php, сравнение, адрес

есть фрагмент кода:

```
function getrIP() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
    }
 
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
 
if (!in_array(getrIP(), array('185.162.128.88'))) {
    exit("Hacking attempt!");
}
```

Как вместо 185.162.128.88 поставить диапазон:

79.142.16.0/20,
195.189.100.0/22,
91.232.230.0/23,
91.213.51.0/24.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: и в чем сложности заключаются? Очевидно, надо определить содержит ли строка диапазон. Если содержит, то выделять эти диапазоны и проверять вхождение. Какие-либо попытки решить задачу у вас были?

Comment: Да и правда, я просто не рассматривал ip2long

Comment: Особенно забавляет то, с каким серьёзным видом проверяется  HTTP_X_REAL_IP, в которое я могу написать что угодно, хоть адрес Белого дома, хоть "фсем чмоке в этом чати!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение на мой вопрос

```
<?php
// проверка IP по маске
function checkIP ($user_ip, $ip_begin, $ip_end) {
 return (ip2long($user_ip)>=ip2long($ip_begin) && ip2long($user_ip)<=ip2long($ip_end));
}

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
checkIP($user_ip, '79.142.16.0', '79.142.31.255') ? 'IP внутри подсети' : exit("Hacking attempt!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Для подобный задач есть несколько библиотек на packagist.org, вот пример одной из таких библиотек от наших китайских друзей:

https://packagist.org/packages/mantoufan/yzhanip

```
(new YZhanIP('127.0.0.1'))->in('127.0.0.1/21'); // true
```

Comment: https://packagist.org/?query=ip%20range%20check